# Cognos Framework manager alternatives on Linux only

Tags: linux, cognos, transformer-model

I asked a question before about if i needed FM installed for Cognos reports to be made.

The response was that i needed at least one FWM package to be published to run a report or that i could use cognos transformer instead..

After looking into this i dont think Transformer is an option, I only have a linux os and cannot use any Windows applications.. To install Transformer i need to install IBM Cognos Transformer client which is on Windows.

Are there any components i could use which only require Linux installations? Windows really isnt an option here.

Comment: What type of package are you trying to publish up?  Are you looking to model regular database tables?  Are you using an OLAP provider?  These things will require different tools.  If you are trying to do most things, you will need a Windows system to install Framework Manager on, as it generally requires it.  An alternative is to create your framework manager model and packages using the Cognos SDK but usually that would be done by those with experience modeling their data in FM already.

Comment: It wasnt overly complex what i was using FM for in the old system, I would create a view in the database and use framework manager to make a project and publish the data items.. Would something simple like that need FM installed?

Comment: Yes, FM is how you develop models and publish packages.